# Need to bind a property in a style at the point that I reference it

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The style I am using contains several elements, but I will show just the horizontal line in my example code here. The StrokeDashArray of the Line is not defined defined yet.

```
    <Style x:Key="YAxisTitleStyle" TargetType="s:AxisTitle">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Line X2="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                              Stroke="{Binding Path=BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type s:YAxis}}}"
                              StrokeThickness="2"
                              StrokeDashArray=""/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I want to define the StrokeDashArray at the point that I use the style.

```
                <YAxis TitleStyle="{StaticResource YAxisTitleStyle}"
                      BorderBrush="{Binding ElementName=HResitivitySeries, Path=SeriesColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}"/>
```

I need to somehow bind the StrokeDashArray for the line in the style to the StrokeDashArray property of the HResistvitySeries. I have no idea how to do this binding, or if it is even possible. I was able to take the stroke of the line from the BorderBrush of the YAxis in order to sync the colors, but the YAxis has no property equivalent to a StrokeDashArray, and the HResistivitySeries is not an ancestor of the YAxis.

Comment: How many color combinations exist? Are there only two, or are there many more colors of (in this example) `Stroke`s?

Comment: What does the `StrokeDashArray` actually depend on? Is it to be declared statically in the `YAxis` element? Or does it depend on some other object? What is the `YAxis` type? Could you add a property to it? Please show [a concise, complete code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that adequately illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `s:AxisTitle` is your own object, add a DependencyProperty to it of type `DoubleCollection` (or if it's not your own object, extend it if possible). Then in the style you can do `StrokeDashArray="{TemplateBinding MyStrokeDashArrayDependencyProperty}"`.  Then you can make multiple other Styles that are `BasedOn` your YAxisTitleStyle and only have a Setter for MyStrokeDashArrayDependencyProperty.  Or if you don't want to make multiple Styles, then you could do something like `StrokeDashArray={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type s:AxisTitle}}, Path=MyStrokeDashArrayDependencyProperty}` and then you just need to update MyStrokeDashArrayDependencyProperty whenever the Style is used.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable suggestion. The object is not mine, I am using the SciChart graphics library. I have already extended some of their classes to get some special behaviors and that works well. From your answer I can see that there is no special XAML magic that I am missing, so you answer seems like the best option.